# How to control chatter feed posts visibility on a record in SF

Tags: chatter, profile

I have customers, partners & employee users, each with their own profile. All 3 of them update the same chatter feed on a record. I want customers to only see what employees post, employees to see what both partners & employees post and for partners to only see what employees post.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal Employees can restrict the visibility of the post in Chatter feed that is either of the following:

- Organization users
- All with Access

For Customers and Partners do not have this option to restrict the visibility.

[image: Partner User post]

So, a record is accessible by Customer, partner and employee then if Customer or Partner posts on chatter feed then Customer and partner can see the post.

Following picture shows how Customer, partner and employee can see the post.

[image: Post visibility]

Finally, your requirement cannot be achieved by OOTB.

Comment: Can't you change the access for the post to "Organization Only"? I don't use chatter but seems it is possible. Unless the setting is for the feed and not an individual post. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DkL7AAK

Comment: Posting to the Organization will not be visible to Customer and partners

Comment: Only Employees can change the post to "Organization Only" which I have mentioned in the first line

Comment: Wonder why the decision was made to not allow the Org or user to control individual visibility of a post....Seems like it would be a valuable option....

Comment: @Eric that would really a good feature if Salesforce provides